# When to use promises or async await?

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, async-await

Is there any way to know when to use Promises vs Async/Await?

I am asking that because it's not so clear for me to know which one performs better, or also is better readable, is there any advantages using each one of them or it doesn't matter?

Thanks!

Comment: Whichever you want. Use either, depending on readability or whichever make you feel comfortable with the code. Also, I would recommend checking this video out : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ho5PnBOoacw

Comment: async | await is more readable.

Comment: @JonasW. it is only preference

Comment: Thats what comments are for :)

Comment: When you want to use a `for` loop instead of recursion you may use `async-await`

Answer (score 1):

They are the same, async/await is a syntactic sugar for promises.

Answer (score 1):

They are exactly the same, so it all comes down to you preference. If you are using a framework, I'd recommend you use the way they use in the framework for consistency.